# Get product ID by product Name for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the productname and obviously also the URL like so: product/productname in woocommerce, but I can't find a way to get the id of the product with this information.

Comment: you can use the get_page_by_title( 'Product Title', OBJECT, 'product' );
this way you can get the product id

Comment: Please insert your code to your question! Without code it's hard to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below code

```
$product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' );
```

Better explanation for your question .

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/get-product-details-by-url-key-in-wordpress-woocommerce

Comment: please do accept the answer as accepted answer this would help others in this way

Comment: This is a php snippet but he is asking how to do it with JavaScript only

Answer (score 1):

Well the accepted answer works on php file then you can embed php in your javascript using `<?= ?>` however there's an easier way of getting woocommerce product_id in a standalone JavaScript file, you just simply get the data attribute of the add-to-cart DOM element:

`$('[name="add-to-cart"]').val()`